# How to set the `ng-include` path by dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

I have a content with 8 blocks in the page. when user clicks on each, I am opening a `pop-up` and showing the same content there. so I have 8 popup contents separately.

When each of the block clicked i am making that view as `true`. so according to the current view, i would like to change the `pop-up` (include) content to be changed. but not working.

here is my pop-up : html:

```
<div class='ng-modal' ng-if="modal.isOpen">
    <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='modal.hide()'></div>
        <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>
        <div class='ng-modal-dialog-content'>
         <ng-include ng-if="modal.board1" src="'../views/projectSummary/modals/{{currentView}}.html'"></ng-include>
         {{currentView}} //it works!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my controller i am setting :

```
$scope.currentView = "board1";
```

so, my html let load from :

```
'../views/projectSummary/modals/board1.html'
```

[Click here to see my Error :](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=%27..%2Fviews%2FprojectSummary%2Fmodals%2F%7B%7BcurrentView%7D%7D.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better/cleaner to set the URL of the partial in the controller, so this becomes a non-issue and you could just do:

```
<ng-include src="currentViewURL">
```

but to answer your question:

```
<ng-include src="'../views/projectSummary/modals/' + currentView + '.html">
```

Comment: As like you say, It is working fine. I am not getting any error. but I coun't see any html loaded inside. I am using your first approach

Comment: @3gwebtrain, I'm somewhat confused by your comment... Just to clarify - both approaches that I provided would work

Comment: Now in controller.js I set : `$scope.currentPopupView= '../views/projectSummary/modals/board1.html';` and in the `include` this now `<ng-include  ng-src="currentPopupView"></ng-include>` - But html content is not there.

Comment: @3gwebtrain, then it is a different issue (e.g. wrong url - it should be relative to your "index.html"). Here's an example that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/iP680dyfTLpBH3PtCg9c?p=preview

Comment: I am getting error as  : ` Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined` - if possible please post some clue.

Comment: @3gwebtrain, ok, this is clearly not part of the code you posted... so, it's a different issue

Comment: Thanks. it works. I didn't insist to post answer. I requested a clue. but thanks for your time.

Comment: @3gwebtrain, and my clue was - "it's a different issue", which is the only clue I could have provided :)

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.2 you can only bind one expression to *[src], *[ng-src] or action. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to-src-ng-src-or-action-).

Write a function in your scope to return the concatenated result:

```
$scope.getSrc = function (viewName) {
  return '../views/projectSummary/modals/' + viewName + '.html';
};
```